# django threadedcomment setup

Tags: django, comments

im trying to use [django threaded comments](http://ericflo.github.com/django-threadedcomments/) however im stuck in how to correctly set values in this:

```
{% get_comment_form for [object] as [varname] with [parent_id] %}

{% get_comment_form for [app].[model] [object_id] as [varname] with [parent_id] %}
{% render_comment_form for [object] with [parent_id] %}
{% render_comment_form for [app].[model] [object_id] with [parent_id] %}.
```

can someone pls point me to a complete tutorial in setting this up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any good tutorials, but it's pretty straight forward as using the template tags.  It is exactly like using the built-in comments template tags with the exception of `parent_id`, since we need to know which comment you are replying to.

Let's say you have a blog app and you are passing a Post object through your views.  Let's call this object `post`.

To render the main comment form for the `post` object:

```
{% render_comment_form for post %}
```

You will be able to make comments that are related to this `post` object.

Then, to render the comment form for each individual comment (or the "reply" if you will), you can use the same template tag but pass in the parent_id of the comment:

```
{% render_comment_form for post with comment.id %}
```